# Foundation framework: My code stacks vertically when I think I followed the example to make them stack horizontally

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation, frontend

I wrote the following for a page in Foundation.  I relocated some of the standard files and folders, hence the amended file paths.

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/foundation.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/app.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <!--
    <div class="row">
      <ul class="pagination" role="navigation">
        <li class="menu-text">Understood</li>
        <li class="disabled">First</li>
        <li class="disabled">Previous</li>
        <li class="disabled">Next</li>
        <li class="disabled">Last</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    -->

    <div class="row">
      <div class="large-4 columns">
        <!--
        <ul class="menu vertical">
          <li><button class="button">Home</button></li>
          <li><button class="button">Map</button></li>
          <li><button class="button">1. Prehistory</button></li>
          <li><button class="button">2. Ancient</button></li>
          <li><button class="button">3. Classical</button></li>
        </ul>
        -->
        <p>First Bunch</p>
      </div>
      <div class="large-8 columns">
        <p>Text</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="../js/vendor/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/vendor/what-input.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/vendor/foundation.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I've left in some comments because, when I rendered the code in the comments, except for the stuff that is supposed to render columns, it works.  However, I'm slowly building up to trying to learn how to make menu bars, and the row containing columns was supposed to be a first attempt at it--so I want the first `<div class="large-4 columns">` to contain the menu bar on the left, and the second `div` to contain the page body.  However, as it is now, this renders as just

> First bunch
>
> Text

rather than placing them in a left column and right column.  As far as I can tell I'm following these instructions correctly:

https://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/v/5.5.3/components/grid.html

I'm also doing this on my desktop computer so I don't think it should be regarding the screen size as anything but large. I'm using the latest version of Firefox on a Linux machine to view it, and the developer console shows no errors.

Answer (score 0):

it seems like your css file is not loading, try this `<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/foundation.css" />` and delete the `../` part.

i hope it will work :-)

best regards, georg

Comment: Nope, the change didn't fix it.  And I added the `../` part because I had located my files in a different directory.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems correct compared with foundation documentation and I haven't been able to find different documentation about the grid implementation for the Foundation version you seem to be using.

What I can think is if you're sure using the same version of foundation than the link you shared (5.5.3). The [latest version docs](https://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/xy-grid.html) says Foundation 6 comes with the layout grid disabled by default. It also recommends to use the XY grid, if you don't need to support IE 10.

That would look like this:

```
<div class="grid-x">
  <div class="cell large-4">First element</div>
  <div class="cell large-6">Next element</div>
</div>
```

Cheers,